# What is the easy way to share AWS Cost & Usage Report to another account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cost-management

I have some AWS accounts that is not under an AWS Organization, one is used as master account, the others as member account. I want to export AWS Cost & Usage Report by CSV to master account S3 bucket, and use it in QuickSight.

Of course I can create a lambda function in each member accounts, use a `PutObject` trigger and transfer CSV files to master account.

But is there an easier way to do that?

※Some thing like use a cross account S3 bucket as member account AWSCUR export destination, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way to export AWS Cost & Usage reports to an S3 bucket owned by another account.

Your problem is exactly why AWS Organisations exist - to view & analyse collated data.

---

If for whatever reason you can't use AWS Organisations, you have 2 "easy" options:

1. Allow [cross-account access](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/) to the S3 bucket containing the CUR
2. Create a [replication rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication.html) to copy the reports inside the S3 "member" accounts automatically to the master account S3 bucket